# Putting objects into java.util.Properties

Tags: java

I'm trying to understand why java.util.Properties was implemented in this way. It has two interfaces: getProperty/setProperty which only accepts strings, and put/get which accepts any object as a value. These two interfaces appear to be overlapping, so a string added with put() can be retrieved using getProperty().

There seems to be some problems with this weird hybrid interface. Putting an object that overrides a string property has the side-effect of clearing the string value, producing null as the getProperty result. Adding an integer, or some other value that has a simple string translation, might be misunderstood as being a real property value (but as a property it's always null).

My question is: Is there a real, practical reason for this? Or is it a half-baked implementation as I suspect?

Comment: I can't back it up, but I'd strongly suspect the problem is backwards compatibility. `Properties` extends `Hashtable`, which is an old class from before generics; that means that if you had a `Properties`, you could have called `properties.put(whatever, whateverElse)` into it. When generics came along, the Java folks wanted to keep code backwards compatible, which meant having it extend `Hashtable<Object, Object>`.

Comment: `Properties` is a subclass of `Hashtable`, with no override of `get`/`put`, hence the behavior. `getProperty`/`setProperty` are typed versions of `get`/`put`. It's a matter of history and not hiding get/put.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[Joshua Bloch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joshua_Bloch) mentions this explicitly in [Effective Java](https://books.google.com/books/about/Effective_Java.html?id=ZZOiqZQIbRMC)

> [*from Chapter 4*] In the case of `Properties`, the designers intended that only strings be allowed as keys and values, but direct access to the underlying `Hashtable` allows this invariant to be violated.  Once this invariant is violated, it is no longer possible to use other parts of the Properties API (`load` and `store`).  By the time this problem was discovered, it was too late to correct it because clients depended on the use of nonstring keys and values.

That text is in context of using composition over inheritance. He's basically using this as an example of when composition should be used instead of inheritance.  If `Properties` wrapped a `Map` instead of extending one, it could have enforced the invarient of using `String` as keys and values.

So the answer is:  It was an oversight.

Comment: Choosing this answer because it explains why it was implemented this way, more than just "don't use the other methods". As a side note, the java mail API uses this by design for configuring a custom SSL socket factory. Oh java, the love-hate relationship we have.

Answer (score 8):

Access to `put` and `get` is a result of `Properties` being an extension of [`Hashtable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html), and the two method should not be used (but cannot be hidden from implementation due to their public access in the superclass).

The [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) have a nice note about why you shouldn't use those methods, and should instead only use strings:

> Because `Properties` inherits from `Hashtable`, the `put` and `putAll` methods can be applied to a `Properties` object. Their use is strongly discouraged as they allow the caller to insert entries whose keys or values are not `Strings`. The `setProperty` method should be used instead. If the `store` or `save` method is called on a "compromised" `Properties` object that contains a non-`String` key or value, the call will fail. Similarly, the call to the `propertyNames` or `list` method will fail if it is called on a "compromised" `Properties` object that contains a non-`String` key.

As @yshavit notes, it'd make more sense for `Properties` to extend `Hashtable<String, String>` than a hashtable of two objects, but this was likely a decision made to maintain backwards compatibility, as any programs using `get`/`put` with any non-String objects would have been broken by such a change.

Comment: But that doesn't address a crucial part of the question, which is why the get/put methods work on `Object` instead of `String`. That is, why doesn't it extend `Hashtable<Object, Object>`? (Per my comment above, I strongly suspect it's for backwards compatibility -- but I don't have specific evidence.)

Comment: @yshavit Good note; I agree that it's almost definitely for backwards compatibility, and I've added such a note into the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Official documentations says

> Because Properties inherits from Hashtable, the put and putAll methods can be applied to a Properties object. Their use is strongly discouraged as they allow the caller to insert entries whose keys or values are not Strings. The setProperty method should be used instead. If the store or save method is called on a "compromised" Properties object that contains a non-String key or value, the call will fail. Similarly, the call to the propertyNames or list method will fail if it is called on a "compromised" Properties object that contains a non-String key.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html

Answer (score 1):

From the [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#getProperty(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

> Because Properties inherits from Hashtable, the put and putAll methods
>   can be applied to a Properties object. Their use is strongly
>   discouraged as they allow the caller to insert entries whose keys or
>   values are not Strings. The setProperty method should be used instead.
>   If the store or save method is called on a "compromised" Properties
>   object that contains a non-String key or value, the call will fail.
>   Similarly, the call to the propertyNames or list method will fail if
>   it is called on a "compromised" Properties object that contains a
>   non-String key.

Answer (score 0):

`Properties` extends `Hashtable`, so you can use `Properties` anywhere you can use a `Hashtable`.

The `Hashtable` class is where the `get()` and `put()` functions are coming from.

Answer (score 0):

`put(key, value)` and `get(key)` are remainders of a questionable decision to have `Properties` extend `Hashtable` back in the day. This behavior can't be changes since it will break backwards compatibility, but any half decent style guide, including the API documentation itself, will recommend to never use these methods.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you're only supposed to use it for Strings. There are ways of serializing an object as a string and retrieving it, but obviously it's not meant for that. I understand that it's really annoying since its the closest you can get to a cross-platform way of saving and retrieving app data. As far as I know there's no official way to save things other than strings in a folder that is hidden from the user, despite the fact that most operating systems have appdata directories.